# UITableViewCell resize after click, constraints are changing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have TableViewCell filled with data. I want to show only one label for example, and after user clicks cell will resize and show all data to user. I'm done with resizing part, but when cell is small it automaticly change my constraints. Can somebody help me ? code nd photos below.

Thanks!

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (i != indexPath.row) {
        i = indexPath.row
    }
    else {
        i = -1
    }
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if (indexPath.row == i) {
        return 250
    }
    else {
        return 50
    }
}
```

[image: before user clicks]

[image: after user clicks]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the cell is at a height of 50 your constraints are being broken because there is not enough space to accommodate them all as you wanted them to be laid out. Therefore, the height of the cell is being honored before any other constraints you added to elements within the cell and thus they are squished together.

To eliminate constraint errors, play around with the priority and relation modes on your constraints.

Lastly, when your cells are collapsed, you can hide all other labels except the one you want to display by calling the following on ones that should be hidden:

```
label.hidden = true
```

Or animate their disappearance like so:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        label.alpha = 0            
    }, completion: { completed -> Void in
            label.hidden = true
})
```

And do the opposite to make them reappear when you expand the cells.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had a View inside my Cell and there were constraints to margins.. I just set this View constraints to constant high and its working now...